Advice for pooling DB connections with serverless
I have a great, working web application which uses SvelteKit, DrizzleORM, a PostgreSQL database running on Amazon RDS. It is hosted on Netlify, which means that the “backend” consists of one big serverless function (sveltekit-render) which handles all the SSR stuff that SvelteKit provides but also, crucially, makes a bunch of queries to the PostgreSQL database. I have a sort of custom-built HTTP REST API which is part of the same SvelteKit application.
I don’t have to worry about huge traffic volumes, but when we got a few hundred people to connect at once, the whole thing came crashing down because the DB hit its connection limit almost immediately (100+ connections).
I think that the issue is that Netlify spins up as many instances of the “sveltekit-render” function as it thinks is necessary - great for initial responsiveness of the site, but a nightmare for proliferating hundreds of simultaneous DB connections! Enabling the pooling feature provided by Drizzle (via postgres-nodejs) doesn’t really help much, because the instances of the “server” process don’t persist long enough to take much advantage of pooling, and in any case there isn’t any really anything to “share” between the instances anyway. At least, this is my understanding of the root cause.
Any thoughts on a good way to solve this problem? I could move away from Netlify entirely, and try to keep a single, more traditional single-server approach. At worst, this would slow down some parts of the site slightly, but would likely keep minimal database connections open (they could all be pooled for the single server). Or is there another way to keep the Netlify “serverless” architecture but somehow separate the SvelteKit “rendering” process from the “REST API” process, and get the API part to somehow handle more simultaneous requests, on a single (or very few) set of database connections?

I might have solved my own problem  Supabase provides a Postgres DB but with their own automatic "connection pooler" in front of the database. Perfect for serverless setup like this. Each function invocation connects with its "own" client connection, but Supabase proxies the connection and re-uses connections to the actual database behind it. So far, seems to help a lot!
From the Supabase docs (Drizzle is mentioned specifically):

Every Supabase project comes with a connection pooler for managing
connections to your database. The pooler provides 2 important
services:
It manages connections for applications that connect and disconnect
from the database frequently. For example, serverless functions and
ORMs such as Prisma, Drizzle, and Kysely often make and drop
connections to the database. If they connected directly each time,
they would quickly exhaust your database server's memory. To connect
to your database efficiently with such tools, you need a pooler.

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/connecting-to-postgres#connection-pooler

AWS also provides a proxy as well...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711320/handling-aws-rds-connection-pooling-with-postgres-13-and-node-lambdas

if you have an always on database, do "serverless" functions really help you?
